# Mostrar lista de datas com setas de movimentação?

Tags: html, css

Gostaria de saber como fazer uma espécie de slide com datas, com setas nos lados caso a  ultrapasse uma width especifica. Isto é o que tenho. O que preciso é de uma espécie de sistema de paginação, mas que não altere qualquer informação no site, só algo visual.

```
<div style="padding:20px;padding-top:0;width:100%;background:#333;color:white;text-align:center;">
    <ul style="display:inline;list-style:none;" id="ull">
        <li style="text-align:left;"><h2 style="padding:0;">Galeria de Fotos</h2></li>
        <li style="display: inline;"><a>2000</a></li>
        <li style="display: inline;"><a>2011</a></li>
        <li style="display: inline;"><a>2012</a></li>
        <li style="display: inline;"><a>2000</a></li>
        <li style="display: inline;"><a>2011</a></li>
        <li style="display: inline;"><a>2012</a></li>
        <li style="display: inline;"><a>2000</a></li>
        <li style="display: inline;"><a>2011</a></li>
        <li style="display: inline;"><a>2012</a></li>
        <li style="display: inline;"><a>2000</a></li>
        <li style="display: inline;"><a>2011</a></li>
        <li style="display: inline;"><a>2012</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Já tentou usar o Bootstrap para isso?

[Exemplo no w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp)

Comment: Não é bem disso que precisava, eu precisava de um plugin que mostrasse por exemplo, das datas desde 200 a 2010, depois tinha a seta para o lado onde houvesse mais.